# TensorFlow, how to index so that (batch_size x num_labels)+(batch_size) -> (batch_size)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, tensorflow

Suppose I just have got a matrix (`2D tensor`) `X`, whose shape is (`batch_size x num_labels`). And the scores of labels for each sample are stored in the matrix. Now I want to extract the true labels' scores, while the true labels are stored in another `1D tensor` `y`, whose shape is (batch_size). 
What can I do ?
I know that in Theano or Numpy. It can be done with a single expression: `X[y]`.
BUT in TensorFlow, what is the most convenient or cost-less way to achieve that ?

```
X = tf.get_variable("X",[batch_size,num_labels])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[batch_size])
```

Note `0 <= y[i] <= num_labels - 1`. The output `z` should be `1D` `tensor` where `z[i]= X[i][y[i]]`

Comment: Could you give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey.  I add a example.  Am I clear.? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that X is a vector containing probabilities for each class and batch instance and that you want to get the probability of the true label. I propose on solution, though it may not be the optimal one:

```
# Create mask for values
increasing = tf.range(start=0, limit=tf.shape(X)[0], delta=1)

# Concatenate batch index and true label
# Note that in Tensorflow < 1.0.0 you must call tf.pack
mask = tf.stack([increasing, y], axis=1)

# Extract values
masked = tf.gather_nd(params=X, indices=mask)
```

Hope it helps.